# How do I connect the mysql server that is running off of my phone to my mac using php and dreamweaver?

Tags: php, android, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I have the app called "Servers Ultimate Pro" on my rooted android phone.

I have created a MySQL, PHP with PHPMyAdmin, web server for remote connection, and webdav server for testing on it.

I am connected to it on my mac using dreamweaver which syncs the php files to my phone.

In PHPMyAdmin, I have created the database `serverdata` and the table `users`.

I am trying to figure out how I can connect the MySQL database on my phone to the database.

I am trying to create a login system.

On 'servers ultimate pro', the mysql address is 192.168.x.xx:3306.

My question is on PHP when I create the function that connects to MySQL database from my phone to my mac.

One thing, I do not have root access on my mac and I cannot do that so I used my phone as a server for hosting it but I want to learn how to connect PHP to MySQL.

Comment: Your question is onelargeblockoftext. Could you add some paragraphs to make it more readable? It's hard to see what your actual problem is as it is. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I recommend this framework that a lows you to connect and do any request to your mysql from PHP. because mysql_connect is deprecated and you should use mysqli that's why I recommend this framework. https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class About the user to connect to root, check the documentation in Servers Ultimate Pro to the the username for the root user

Answer (score 0):

you can create a database class (like the one provided below) inlcude this in your application and create a new db object. Firstly define connection paramters and then create a new db object.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'host');
define('DB_NAME', 'db name');
define('DB_USER', 'user name');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');



 $db = new DatabaseService();
```

Database class as follows

```
  class DatabaseService {

//construct the connection
public function __construct() {
  $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  if ($this->conn->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed To Connect to MySQLi: " . $conn->connect_error;
  }
}

//Run a mysqli query with the entered string
public function execute_query($qry) {
  $result = $this->conn->query($qry);

  if ($this->conn->error) {
      try {    
          throw new Exception('MySQL error' .  $this->conn->error . '<br> Query:<br>' . $qry . ', ' . $this->conn->errno);    
      } catch(Exception $e) {
          echo "Error No: ".$e->getCode(). " - ". $e->getMessage() . "<br >";
          echo nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
      }
  } else {
    return $result;
  }
}

// Execute query and return assoc array
public function execute_assoc_query($qry) {
  $rows = array();
  if($result = $this->execute_query($qry)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

// Return ID of newly inserted item
public function execute_query_id($qry) {
  $this->execute_query($qry);
  return $this->conn->insert_id;
}
}
```

This can be used by then calling to the db and passing a query string.

```
$users = $db->execute_assoc_query('SELECT * FROM users');
```

for more information tho i suggest reading the php docs on mysqli [php mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: How do you create a user name and password for mysql to connect to?

Comment: you should already have one if you can log into php my admin however you can create users in the php my admin menu. Click on the users tab to see a list of current users or add a new one.

Comment: So, I use the user and password I made in phpmyadmin to connect to mysql in a php doc? like this?    mysql('192.168.x.xx:3306, 'root', 'root', DB_NAME);

Comment: yes just make sure you use the new keyword because your creating a new mysqli object and passing it the connection parameters.

Comment: I keep getting this error message:  "HTTP Error Code 501 Not Implemented"

Comment: if the script is running on the same server as the db try using localhost as the server

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong.  I was using the wrong testing server.  I should have been using RDS server instead of the webDAV server.

Answer (score 0):

It's because mysql default security settings.  User root limited to login in localhost. So what you have to do is :

1、use any mysql client run in the **PHONE**
2、login as root
3、update mysql.user set host='%' where user='root';
4、FLUSH PRIVILIGE

and this will allow root user can login from your pc.